# PostgreSQL: count() or keep a counter?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in a one-to-many relationship. Let's say that for each row in table `foo`, there can be 0 or more rows in table `bar` that reference the row in `foo`.

The client wants to know how many rows in `bar` reference a row in `foo`, for all the rows in `foo`.

I can accomplish this with the following query:

```
SELECT count(bar_id) FROM bar WHERE bar.foo_id = foo.foo_id;
```

However, what if the tables `foo` and `bar` were large? Say `foo` has 1 million rows, and `bar` has 10 million rows. Let's also say that 99% of rows in `foo` would have a count of less than 1,000 `bar` rows referencing it. Let's say that the client typically asks for around 100 rows of `foo` at a time.

Should I use the naive count() query with an index on the foreign key, or would it be better to keep a counter? Is it even possible to keep a counter? By updating the counter with atomic increments and decrements using a trigger on `bar`, I believe it's possible, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps counter-intuitively, you'll probably find that the simple `count` approach is faster unless your workload is very biased towards reads.

The reason for this is that the effect of the counter table will be to serialize updates, so only one transaction that's updating a given `foo` can be in flight at any given time. That's because the update for the trigger that updates the counter will take a lock on that `foo`'s entry in the counter table and won't release it until the transaction rolls back or commits.

Worse, if your transaction affects more than one `foo` and so does another one, you have a high chance of one of the transactions being aborted due to a deadlock.

Stick to a simple count until you have a good reason to change it.

Comment: Here, what is referred to what? By "simple count" you mean count() or maintaining a counter variable?

Answer (score 4):

The sweet thing about indices is that they offer logarithmic complexity for querying operations. Thus, for `10*10^6` rows, the index just needs about `ln(10*10^6)=16.1` comparisons to find one specific id. Make it 100 million rows, and you only have to do 2 to 3 comparisons more. In short: The index does not that much care about the size of a table.

Of course, you may still be able to archive some performance gains using a stored counter. That is a typical tradeoff. Maintaining the counter will make insertions and deletions to `bar` much more expensive and make your counting query a little bit cheaper.

Thus, if your tables are altered rarely and the query is run frequently (say, thousands of times an hour), you might really gain performance using the stored counter procedure. However, in most cases I would say go for the indexed column and let the database do the rest for you.

Comment: So for 100 million rows, how much time complexity it has for counting certain records?